# Share Sessions with Main Domain to Subdomain Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session-cookies

Hello everyone I want to share the sessions from my main domain with is https://www.waraywarayako.ph/ and my subdmain is https://forum.waraywarayako.ph/ once the user is already login its either in my main domain or subdomain they dont need to relogin again from my forum or main script.

Here is my Config codes in waraywarayako.ph:

```
$config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration']      = 7200;
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = FALSE;
$config['sess_use_database']    = FALSE;
$config['sess_table_name']      = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']        = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']  = 300;

$config['cookie_prefix'] = "etc_anything_";
$config['cookie_domain'] = ".waraywarayako.ph";
$config['cookie_path'] = "/";
$config['cookie_secure'] = FALSE;
```

Here is my Config codes in forum.waraywarayako.ph:

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'sessions';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = FCPATH . 'application/sessions/';
$config['sess_match_ip'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
//NOTE THIS SESSION IS FOR MY ADD VIEW FUNCTION
$config['cookie_prefix']    = '';
$config['cookie_domain']    = '';
$config['cookie_path']      = '/';
$config['cookie_secure']    = FALSE;
$config['cookie_httponly']  = FALSE;
```

I hope anyone can help me with this.. thank you

Comment: From a user perspective I'm off your site the second I see disable add block to continue. I haven't been to Forbes since they started. I understand that you probably make money from ads, but its nowhere near as much money as you loose from not having users but thats just my two cents.

Comment: ill disable that later when i use pc

Comment: Its been remove just now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello every one I just wanted to share it to you the sharing sessions is now workin.. Happy new year everyone..

```
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'sessions';
 $config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
 $config['sess_expire_on_close'] = FALSE;
 $config['sess_encrypt_cookie'] = TRUE;
 $config['sess_use_database'] = TRUE;
 $config['sess_table_name'] = 'sessions';
 $config['sess_match_ip'] = TRUE;
 $config['sess_match_useragent'] = FALSE;
 $config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300; 


$config['cookie_prefix'] = 'etc_anything_';
$config['cookie_domain'] = '.waraywarayako.ph';
$config['cookie_path'] = "/";
$config['cookie_secure'] = TRUE;
$config['cookie_httponly']  = FALSE;
```

Answer (score 0):

If both use CI, I would try to put the sessions of the two environments in the same place, a folder on the server that the two can share. (Just a guess)

Something like:

```
$config['sess_save_path'] = '/home/www/yourpath/sessions/';
```

Answer (score 0):

in both configs,

```
$config['sess_save_path'] = FCPATH . 'application/sessions/'; (should be same)
$config['sess_match_ip'] = TRUE;
```

and

```
$config['cookie_prefix'] = "etc_anything_";
$config['cookie_domain'] = ".waraywarayako.ph";
```

Comment: $config['sess_save_path'] = FCPATH . 'application/sessions/'; (should be same) this one is on the forum folder can i call it just like this $config['sess_save_path'] =forum.waraywarayako.ph/ . 'application/sessions/'; ?

Comment: yup that would be fine

Comment: still not working this is what I did $config['sess_save_path'] = 'https://forum.waraywarayako.ph/application/sessions/';

Comment: can you try with an absolute path?

Comment: I will try this again later on the other PC just to make sure if it is really working